# Website local error

Tags: php, html, web

I'm building a website. For some reason when I try to run it on the local host, I get this message:

Access forbidden!

You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403

localhost
Sat Nov 20 22:19:02 2010
Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.8l PHP/5.3.1 mod_perl/2.0.4 Perl/v5.10.1

What should I do to fix this so my website shows up on the local host. The website is coded in html/css/php. Thank you.

Comment: Look if you have a .htacess, perhaps its denying access. just a thought

Comment: might be Iptables that block localhost ..... LOL

Comment: Well, this could be a lot of things (as others have pointed out), but also consider your virtualhost configuration, and make sure that you are listening on all the right interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the error logs.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with trying to read the apache log file for the specific error.

Sometimes, though, a 403 Forbidden error can be a simple permission error. Make sure the web directories are 755 and files are (atleast) 644 (but don't go chmod'ing everything to 777!)

For example,

```
chmod 755 /path/to/you/web/root
echo 'testing.. hello world!' > /path/to/you/web/root/test.php 
chmod 644 /path/to/you/web/root/test.php
```

Hopefully that will get you going. If not, check your apache settings file (usually httpd.conf) and check out any mentioning of you web root. A 403 error can also be caused by apache trying to serve up a directory outside of it's WEBROOT.. meaning the webserver doesn't actually have access to the files.

Good luck.